# How to make subplots work correctly when working with slices of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-analysis

I am trying to plot 4 subplots that break a large data frame into smaller slices so that the bar chart isn't too overwhelming and unreadable.  I have broken the slices apart and assigned them each to individual data frames.  The Dataframe that I am working with looks like this (this dataframe is the unstack output from a multi index data frame (df.unstack()):

```
Age Range   40-49  50-59  60-69  70-79  80+
County                                     
Allen         NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.0
Athens        NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN  NaN
Belmont       NaN    1.0    NaN    1.0  1.0
Clark         NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0  NaN
Columbiana    NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0  NaN
Cuyahoga      NaN    3.0    1.0    7.0  3.0
Defiance      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.0
Franklin      NaN    NaN    4.0    1.0  3.0
Greene        NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN  NaN
Hamilton      NaN    1.0    2.0    1.0  7.0
Hocking       NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0  NaN
Knox          NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.0
Lorain        NaN    NaN    NaN    2.0  NaN
Lucas         NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN  2.0
Madison       1.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
Mahoning      NaN    1.0    NaN    1.0  2.0
Medina        NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN  NaN
Miami         NaN    NaN    1.0    NaN  1.0
Pickaway      NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0  NaN
Portage       1.0    NaN    NaN    2.0  NaN
Ross          NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0  NaN
Seneca        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.0
Shelby        NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.0
Stark         NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0  NaN
Summit        NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0  NaN
Trumbull      NaN    NaN    NaN    1.0  1.0
Warren        NaN    1.0    NaN    NaN  2.0
```

I used the following code to break them into 4 equal slices and assigned them to individual data frames:

```
df1 = df.unstack()[:7]
df2 = df.unstack()[7:14]
df3 = df.unstack()[14:21]
df4 = df.unstack()[21:]
```

I then went to plot them as subplots with the following code:

```
plt.subplot(221)
df1.plot(kind='bar')

plt.subplot(222)
df2.plot(kind='bar')

plt.subplot(223)
df3.plot(kind='bar')

plt.subplot(224)
df4.plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

When I run this code, it outputs the four blank subplots (they're in a 4 rows 1 column format) and then after those four it plots only the last subplot (df4).  If I comment out the plt.subplot() lines, the plots output correctly.  I have plotted things like this in a similar format before so I'm not sure why this won't run the same way, could it have something to do with using slices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot a pandas.DataFrame on a matplotlib subplot you need to:

1. Store the axis returned by `plt.subplot()` call to a variable that you can then
2. Pass this axis to `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` call

Like:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
df1.plot(kind='bar', ax = ax1)
```

Because you're not doing this, every new `plt.subplot()` call creates new figures and overwrites the figures created by `pandas.DataFrame.plot()` call and thus you get 4 figures of empty plots and one figure from `df4.plot(kind='bar')`

What you should do:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot(221)
df1.plot(kind='bar', ax = ax1)

ax2 = plt.subplot(222)
df2.plot(kind='bar', ax = ax2)

ax3 = plt.subplot(223)
df3.plot(kind='bar', ax = ax3)

ax4 = plt.subplot(224)
df4.plot(kind='bar', ax = ax4)

plt.show()
```

**Example output using first two columns of your DataFrame:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I greatly appreciate the high level explanation. I’m very new to coding and am entirely self taught so some of it just kinda goes over my head. Would you happen to have any tips on how to learn things like this at a high level?

Comment: I feel like 'high level' is a bit vague and you might chase that goal all your life. Also, that sort of question is rather opinion based so this is just that. Look for tutorials, free and paid ones, if you run into a problem, search (first, much quicker to find an existing answer than wait for an new one) stackoverflow and relevant documentation; also you can try dividing your code into workable pieces, change it slightly, and see if it behaves as you expect it to. If it doesn't, then there's something to learn there. But, it also depends how you learn, so you gotta to figure that out too.